# Android Disable zoom effect in bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, uinavigationbar, tabview, bottomnavigationview

I was trying to implement bottom navigation bar. Here I am facing a problem when the menu item getting in zoom on click and that leads some title text truncating from the bar.

Like screenshot given
[image][image]

Is there any solution to prevent from this zooming effect?

Comment: provide some code

Answer (score 3):

> Text labels provide **short**, meaningfully definitions to bottom
>   navigation icons. **Avoid long text labels as these labels do not
>   truncate or wrap**.

According to guidelines, you shouldn't use long texts.

[image]

[Source](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style)

Comment: great, but in my case all five options are mandatory. And roughike has option to customize this so that all the options will be visible fine

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is override the dimension for **design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size** in your dimens.xml file.

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override = "true" >12sp</dimen>
```

Here 12sp is the default textsize for **inactive** bottom navigation item. Set the same for **active** bottom navigation item as well. You will have no zoom effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lots of trial and error and now I am realizing that the better option is to use third party library for bottom bar. One of the better solution is [roughike](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) There is lots of customization available

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShifting(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

after this put this

```
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

I have tried this and it works

Answer (score 0):

Just set the type field of your **BottomNavigationBar** widget to BottomNavigationBarType.fixed.

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```